Flutter issue with getZoomLevel for iOS
In flutter I display a GoogleMap widget like so:
   GoogleMap(
          mapType: _mapType,
          initialCameraPosition: _initialRegion,
          onCameraMove: currentMapStatus,
          onMapCreated: (GoogleMapController controller) {
            _controller.complete(controller);
          },
          markers: _markers,
        ),

When loading the markers I get the zoom level like so and it works very well on Android. The zoom level returned is about 15.23.
void loadMarkers(position) async {    
       final GoogleMapController controller = await _controller.future;
       var zoom = await controller.getZoomLevel();
}

The problem is on iOS:
When I open the page the first time the returned zoom level is correct and I get the same as in Android - 15.23.
However, if I open a second instance of the same maps page with the same properties, the zoom level is always 2.0 for the second instance.
Any idea why this is and how to fix it?
